# Is the group of homomorphisms from $G$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ always a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^\kappa$ for some $\kappa$?

Tags: group-theory

Is the group of homomorphisms from $G$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ always a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^\kappa$ for some cardinal $\kappa$?

To be more specific, let $G$ be a group and consider $\hat{G}$, the set of homomorphisms from $G$ to $\mathbb{Z}$. Define the group operation on $\hat{G}$ like so. For $a,b\in \hat{G}$, $a*b$ is the homomorphism defined by $(a*b)(x) = a(x)+b(x)$.

Now consider some group $G$. Must $\hat{G}$ be isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^\kappa$ for some cardinal $\kappa$? If yes I'd be interested in a proof, otherwise a counter example.

Comment: If $\varphi \in \hat{G}$ is a torsion element, there exists an integer$n \ne 0$ s.t. $n\varphi(g) = 0 $ for all $g$. If this holds, since $\mathbb{Z}$ is torsion free, $\varphi(g) = 0$ for all $g \in G$, which means the only torsion element in $\hat{G}$ is zero map. So $\hat{G}$ is torsion free. Does this lead us to the the structure $\hat{G} \equiv \mathbb{Z}^\kappa$? I'm not sure for the infinitely generated case.

Comment: A torsion-free abelian group does not embed in some $\mathbb{Z}^{\kappa}$ in general. A counter-example is $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always write $G$ as a quotient of some free group $F$, so there is a surjective morphism $F\to G$. This induces a morphism
$$\hat{G} = \operatorname{Hom}(G,\mathbb{Z}) \to \operatorname{Hom}(F,\mathbb{Z}) = \hat{F}$$
which is automatically injective. Now if $F$ has rank $\kappa$, then for any abelian group $A$, $\operatorname{Hom}(F,A)\simeq A^\kappa$, so in particular
$\hat{F} \simeq  \mathbb{Z}^\kappa$, and in the end it is true that $\hat{G}$ embeds in some $\mathbb{Z}^\kappa$.

---

In a very explicit way, take a set of generators $\{a_i\}_{i\in \kappa}$ of $G$, and define $\hat{G}\to \mathbb{Z}^\kappa$ by
$$f\mapsto (f(a_i))_{i\in \kappa} .$$

You can check that this defines an injective morphism. (It is the same proof, but with a more explicit description).

Comment: You seems to be assuming that $G$ is abelian here?

Comment: Oh, yes, I don't know why, I was convinced this was an assumption. It still works with a free group instead of a free abelian one though, I'll change it.

Comment: Also, I'm confused by something. Why is $\mathbb{Z}$ not a counter-example? Unless I'm misunderstanding something (which is not unlikely!), $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z})$ embeds into $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})$, and so $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})$ contains torsion, no?

Comment: @user1729 When you write $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z})$, the group law is implicitly function composition, but when we talk about $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})$ we are looking at function addition. So although $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z})$ is a subset of $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})$, it is not a subgroup.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks. (I initially double-checked my understanding with the operation given in the question. It seems that I think that $(-1)+(-1)=0$.)